# How to run all the spec.ts file in Angular 6 using Karma and Jasmine?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have created a project with Angular 6. It is having totally 20 components. I needed to test the application. So I thought of executing basic test cases got generated while creation of components.

I ran `ng test`. But when I do so, only 10 out of 20 components test cases are executing, and other component's `spec.ts` files are not executed. I don't know if I am missing any link for running the test cases.

In my test.ts below configuration is there, which should be responsible to run all the spec.ts files.

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Please suggest to me what I need to, to run all test cases[basic] of all 20 components.

Comment: Look at the `basePath` property in `karma.conf.js`. Is is pointing to a location that would exclude the files?

Comment: The basepath is empty `basePath: ''` in karma.conf.js.

Comment: Are there errors in the test browser's console?

Comment: No errors. If I am writing test cases in app.component.spec.ts, it is working fine. But if I need to test the Login page from its own spec file, it is not executing the login.component.spec.ts.